# MV3 input validation - IE8 & IE9 behave differently

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, client-side-validation

I'm using DataAnnotations to validate my input fields on a MVC3 application. I'm using regular expressions validations.
I get the validation messages on the UI for IE8 & IE9.
But I notice the difference when I hit the Save button even after the client side validation has failed. 
IE9 keeps me on the client side. 
On IE8 however, the control goes to the controller action, and I have to have a controller side TryValidateModel so that the validation errors out.

Does anyone know why IE8 is doing a server round trip?

Edit:
Adding the code. This goes into the cshtml.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Person", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
       <span class="resultError" id="resultError">
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "Name should not contain special characters")  
       </span>
       <table>
         <tr>
          <td class="editor-label">Name:
          </td>
          <td class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
          </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       <input type="submit" name="btnKey" value="Save" />
    }
```

This is the partial class using DataAnnotation. The Person class is driven by EF. So I have to create a metadata class to do the validation.

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(personMetadata))]
    public partial class person: EntityObject
    {
      public class personMetadata
      {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9]+")]       
        public object Name { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

Edit: Adding the javascript files that are referenced.
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"

Comment: Yes, I know why this happens. You just have to show your code.

Comment: @susen, which client side validation library are you using? Did you include the proper scripts?

Comment: Yes - I have the required scripts. The client side validation is working. My question is when I hit the Save button when there's an invalid value in my Name field. IE8 takes me to the action in controller. IE9 stays there.

Comment: @susen, yes this happens because you have some javascript error or some of your client side scripts are not properly referenced. Can you show which client side scripts have you referenced and how are you using them?

Comment: @Darin - I dont see a js error being thrown. I believed the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobstrusive are all that you need to do your client side validations.  On both IE 8 & 9 the validation happens as expected. But its really the Save button that I'm concerned about.

Comment: @Darin I actually have the exact same issue. On Chrome and Firefox the jquery validation works, but in IE8 it goes all the way to the server. I can't pinpoint the error.

Comment: follow this link.It works for me. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?848476-MVC3-Razor-Client-Validation-Problem-in-IE-8-and-Bind-Exclude-Problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, which is a lot like yours, I found that updating jquery.validate.js was the way to go. There is a [reported bug](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/105) on version 1.8.0 of jquery validation about IE 7, 8 and 9.

After getting the latest version everything started to work.

Comment: Thanks Kensai - this worked like a charm. I downloaded the Validation 1.8.1 and it works exactly like I expected.