# dataannotations for required Property not working in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC - 4 Project with Jquery version 1.9.1 and Jquery UI - 1.10.2.
I have Used below code

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Which is working in all the other Browser properly then IE-8.
Can you please suggest me what do I need to do to get it work in IE-8.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's about `jquery.validate.js` version.

Check following suggestions:

[MV3 input validation - IE8 & IE9 behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421554/mv3-input-validation-ie8-ie9-behave-differently)

It was jquery.validate.js that had the issue. Either get a latest version or change

```
return $([]).add(this.currentForm.elements)             
.filter(":input")
```

with

```
return $(':input', this.currentForm)
```

working codes:

```
//return $([]).add(this.currentForm.elements)             
//.filter(":input")             
return $(':input', this.currentForm)             
.not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")             
.not( this.settings.ignore )             
.filter(function() {
    !this.name && validator.settings.debug && window.console && console.error( "%o has no name assigned", this);                              
    // select only the first element for each name, and only those with rules specified                 
    if ( this.name in rulesCache || !validator.objectLength($(this).rules()) )
        return false;                                  
    rulesCache[this.name] = true;                 
    return true;             
});
```

Refrence:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?848476-MVC3-Razor-Client-Validation-Problem-in-IE-8-and-Bind-Exclude-Problem